# regex - repeated or distributed characters

Tags: javascript, java

newbie here on regular expressions hoping to get some help.

I have a task to build a regex based on allowed number of repeated or distributed characters.

Here is the regex that I have built but it is not working, only matches on repeated characters.

```
/(.).*\1{2}/g
```

if my string is `"test"`, the regex should find a match. If the quantifier is 3 and my string is `"1234343"` the regex should find a match.

This task is part of a bigger project where the user can configure settings for both username and password on html page, and on form submit it will call java servlet to construct the regex and save it into the database.

Whenever user navigates to reset password page it will send back the regex to javascript to validate the new password, the validation will also be done on the server-side.

I am trying to build a javascript friendly regex that would also work in java.

Any tips are greatly appreciated.  I know lookbehind in javascript is not supported, but I don't know what else to keep in mind when constructing the regex.

Comment: [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) or [Java](https://www.java.com/en/) ??? They are not the same you know...

Comment: "I am trying to build a javascript friendly regex that would also work in java."
He wants both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
(.)(.*\1){2}
```

This will find a character which is repeated **3** times.

`(.)_________` captures first occurrence of a character.
`___(.*\1)___` finds the character again, after 0 or more other characters ...
`_________{2}` repeating twice, for a total of 3 occurrences.

You needed `(___)`’s around the part you wanted `{__}` repeats.  And you want 1 less than the number of occurrences in the `{__}`, because the `(.)` already counts for 1 occurrence.

Comment: would you mind providing a java version of this regex?  It works in javascript as I would expect but not in java.

Comment: to give some more info, I am using String.matches and I assume the reason why it is not working is because matches automatically adds /^ and $/

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [`Matcher#find`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--).  Something like `Pattern.compile(“(.)(.*\\1){2}”).matcher(“abcbcba”).find()`